# How to inspect a json response from Ansible URI call

Tags: json, sonarqube, uri, ansible

I have a service call that returns system status in `json` format. I want to use the ansible [URI](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) module to make the call and then inspect the response to decide whether the system is up or down

```
{"id":"20161024140306","version":"5.6.1","status":"UP"}
```

This would be the `json` that is returned

This is the ansible task that makes a call:

```
 - name: check sonar web is up
   uri:
    url: http://sonarhost:9000/sonar/api/system/status
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    register: data
```

Question is how can I access `data` and inspect it as per ansible documentation this is how we store results of a call. I am not sure of the final step which is to check the status.

Comment: You can start with simple `debug: var=data` as next task to see what's inside the registered variable. This will help you to move on.

Comment: Thanks that helped break down the issue for me. :)

Comment: Notice how `register` is indented this resulted in `data is undefined` error  to fix this you would need to unindent to same spacing as `uri`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This works for me.

```
- name: check sonar web is up
uri:
  url: http://sonarhost:9000/sonar/api/system/status
  method: GET
  return_content: yes
  status_code: 200
  body_format: json
register: result
until: result.json.status == "UP"
retries: 10
delay: 30
```

Notice that `result` is a ansible dictionary and when you set `return_content=yes` the response is added to this dictionary and is accessible using `json` key

Also ensure you have indented the task properly as shown above.

Comment: This is nice, the fact that result comes in as an Ansible dictionary and there's a Jinja2 JSON parser already there to extract info from it.

Comment: @Halfiz Thank you, thank you, thank you. My until: condition was not working and it was the indentation that was biting me.

Comment: Is it somehow possible using content? For some reason content does not work (probably because of some escaping issues). Could you check that if you have time?

Answer (score 6):

You've made the right first step by saving the output into a variable.

The next step is to use either `when:` or `failed_when:` statement in your next task, which will then switch based on the contents of the variable. There are a whole powerful set of statements for use in these, the [Jinja2 builtin filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters), but they are not really linked well into the Ansible documentation, or summarised nicely.

I use super explicitly named output variables, so they make sense to me later in the playbook :) I would probably write yours something like:

```
- name: check sonar web is up
  uri:
    url: http://sonarhost:9000/sonar/api/system/status
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
  register: sonar_web_api_status_output

- name: do this thing if it is NOT up
  shell: echo "OMG it's not working!"
  when: sonar_web_api_status_output.stdout.find('UP') == -1
```

That is, the text "UP" is not found in the variable's stdout.

Other [Jinja2 builtin filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) I've used are:

- `changed_when: "'<some text>' not in your_variable_name.stderr"`
- `when: some_number_of_files_changed.stdout|int > 0`

The [Ansible "Conditionals" docs page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) has some of this info. [This blog post](http://hakunin.com/six-ansible-practices) was also very informative.

Comment: posted about the same time as my answer :) so now I am not sure which one to mark as correct answer as both seem to work

Comment: Hehe ok :) Sorry I took a bit to write that.

Comment: how to say the site is UP by looking at status_code?

Comment: `register` is too indented, it needs to spaces less

Comment: The 'Jinja2 builtin filters' link 404s now, sadly, as does the 'Ansible "Conditionals" docs page'.

Comment: @JesseAdelman Thanks, I’ve updated those links now.

Answer (score 5):

As per documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html

Whether or not to return the body of the response as a "content" key in the dictionary result. Independently of this option, if the reported Content-type is "application/json", then the JSON is always loaded into a key called json in the dictionary results.

```
---
- name: Example of JSON body parsing with uri module
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Example of JSON body parsing with uri module
      uri: 
        url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 200
        body_format: json
      register: data
      # failed_when: <optional condition based on JSON returned content>

    - name: Print returned json dictionary
      debug:
        var: data.json

    - name: Print certain element
      debug:
        var: data.json[0].address.city
```

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of checks can be easily carried out in the same task to be performed. E.g.

```yaml
- name: do something if Sonar web is up
  debug:
    msg: 'We are doing something.'
  vars:
    response: '{{ lookup('url', 'http://sonarhost:9000/sonar/api/system/status') | from_json }}'
  when: response.status == 'OK'
```